# Object Oriented Database like Caché but that is free and for .NET?

Tags: database

Is there any alternative to caché that is as performant and scalable but free ?and if possible for .NET ?

Comment: there is db4o, but it is in-memory, meaning that it satisfies only "free" requirement.

Comment: @Chris ok, sorry for disinformation.

Comment: I have seen db4o but they don't seem to be really focused on scalability and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VelocityDB](http://www.velocitydb.com) is not free but not expensive, $400 for a developer license. It is a true object database implemented using only C# code. It most likely outperformes Cache. See some other comparisons [here](http://www.velocitydb.com/Compare.aspx).

Comment: Problem is that VelocityDB requires you to inherit from certain objects, if I understand it correctly, which pretty much ties you down to that db, and also forces you to change code in your classes, and thats not fun for anyone.

Comment: No, VelocityDB does not require you to inherit from a certain base class but usually you will want to for efficiency.